# When using spring rest docs, how do I make a newline in the description?

Tags: spring, spring-restdocs

I tried \n or br tag to make a newline, but it doesn't work.

```
requestParameters(
                parameterWithName("name").description("This is the description <br/> in the table."),
```

```
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">This is the description &lt;br/&gt; in the table.</p></td>
```

how do I make a newline in the description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to combine an extra `"+"` in the string with the newline character `\n`.

```
parameterWithName("name").description("This is the description +" + "\n" + "in the table."),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was so hard because of this. It was solved because of you.